# Combining two queries (Sub Query)

Tags: oracle10g

I have 2 tables in Oracle 10g.

table 1:

```
loan_id   installment
   1         500
   2         600
   3         800
```

table 2:

```
loan_id   amount     date
   1        200      5/Jan/2014
   3        800      20/Jan/2014
```

Step1:Selecting all rows within a particular date range.

```
Select * from table2 where date>a and date<b
```

Step2:Selecting all rows from table 2 whose loan_id is not in result set of step1.

```
Select * from table1 where loan_id NOT IN (Select loan_id from table2 where date>a and date<b )
```

Step3: I also want to select those loan_id whose amount(of table2) is less than installment (of table2).

My question can we combine step 2 and step 3 in a single query?

Thanks.

EDIT:

The following combined query gives me the output.

```
Select alias.loan_id from ((Select * from
transactions where date>2 and date<6)as alias) inner join loansapproved l on 
alias.loan_id = l.loan_id where alias.amount<l.installment
UNION 
Select l.loan_id from loansapproved l left join transactions t
on l.loan_id=t.loan_id where l.loan_id not in(Select loan_id from
transactions where date>2 and date<6) ;
```

Could anyone simplify this one?

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you can do that. Did you try using joins? something like  :: Select t1.loan_id from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.loan_id=t2.loan_id where t1.loan_id NOT IN (Select loan_id from table2 where date>a and date<b ) and t2.amount<t1.installment

Comment: this is not fetching me those loan_ids in table 2,whose amount is lesser than installment.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
Select t1.loan_id from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.loan_id=t2.loan_id where t2.amount<t1.installment
and t2.date<a and t2.date>b
```

Comment: check the sqlFiddle --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5123/6, Let me kknow if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have edited my question. Could you please look through that and give me some suggestions.

Comment: @Gayathri... just now i looked into your query. I need the entry with loan_id 2 also.